# WCF fails when returning data

Tags: c#, wcf, return

My first forays into WCF. The class `HardDrive` goes and collects a bunch of WMI information about locally connected drives. For some reason, when it attempts to return the `List<HardDrive>` to the client, I get

> *The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.*

Which is one of those totally unhelpful error messages.

I've done step-by-step debugging, so I *know* it's crashing when it tries to return the list back to the client. I just don't know *why*.

My best guess is something to do with the size of the returned list, but...it's not going to be that big, I wouldn't think?

I've tested this returning a basic string and it works fine.

```
namespace FCopyDataService
{
    public class FCopyDataService : IFCopyDataService
    {
        public List<HardDrive> GetAllHardDrives()
        {
            return HardDrive.GetHardDrives(); //this returns quite happily
        }

        public List<Partition> GetAllPartitions(HardDrive currentDrive)
        {
            return HardDrive.GetPartitions(currentDrive);
        }
    }
}
```

I call it from the client using:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FCopyDataServiceClient drives = new FCopyDataServiceClient();
    drives.Open(); //checks it's open
    List<HardDrive> receivedDrives = drives.GetAllHardDrives(); //crashes here
}
```

My service config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

And my client config, with some odd bits because I've been trying to work this out.

```
<system.serviceModel>
          <bindings>
               <basicHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFCopyDataService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                         openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                         maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                         <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                         <security mode="None">
                              <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                                   realm="" />
                              <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                         </security>
                    </binding>
               </basicHttpBinding>
          </bindings>
          <client>
               <endpoint address="http://localhost:19140/FCopyDataService.svc"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFCopyDataService"
                    contract="FCopyDataService.IFCopyDataService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFCopyDataService" />
          </client>
       <behaviors>
         <endpointBehaviors>
           <behavior>
             <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
           </behavior>
         </endpointBehaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
           <behavior >
             <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
             <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
             <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
           </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
       </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Is the HardDrive class serializable?

Comment: Also worth noting that you do have fairly low limits on the size/length of the returned data.  As you mention, depending on the amount of data, this may also be a cause.

Comment: I would enable WCF trace logging, and see if you get any better error information in the trace log.

Comment: Enable WCF service log file which should show you the error in more detail. Please refer to this link to enable logging in the web.config: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

Comment: @GrantH. - I haven't specifically made it so. I take it the HardDrive class would need to be serializable as a basic pre-req to working through WCF?

Comment: @DavidM, that's correct, assuming you wrote that class, you'll need to ensure you are using serializable types, and add the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` decorations.  Otherwise, you'll need to create a new class that can be serialized and copy the information as necessary to the serializable class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HardDrive` class had to be serialized, but it also contained a cyclical reference to `Partitions`.

So I changed `Partitions` to include `[DataContract(IsReference=true)]` and removed `HardDrives` as a `[DataMember]` of partitions, which seemed to do the trick for my purposes, but I feel isn't the best answer.